# Mysql, how to get rid from duplicated records, joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Lets imagine two tables:

```
username
 id, name
 1   username1
 2   username1
 3   username2

emails
 id, user, name
 1   1     assdf@sdf.hu
 2   2     afgdf@sdf.hu
 3   3     gfg@sdf.hu
```

the problem is there are duplicated entries. I cant simply drop them, because records are connected to them, so they get lost. (for example afgdf@sdf.hu email address). How to solve it?

Comment: so if theere are multiple records, which of them would like to retrieve? in the case of `username.id`

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86925/1)

First you should update table `emails` to replace `user` with right values to eliminate values to be deleted.

```
update emails set user=(select min(id) 
                        from username 
                       where name=
                      (select name from username where id=emails.user));
```

Now delete from `username` table duplicate records. We keep only records with MINIMAL `id` for each `name`:

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM username t1
LEFT JOIN (select min(id) mid from username group by name) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.mid
WHERE t2.mid is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

`update emails set user=1 where user=2` and then you can simply drop row containing **id 2** in  **username** table

Answer (score 0):

update your username tabel. For every name that is duplicate (triplet, quat...), update the emails table and replace the user with the original user id.